# Group by List using inner list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Below is my List collection.

```
public class A
{
    public String id{ get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public List<B> nestedList { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public String innerid{ get; set; }
    public string innername { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use group by on nested collection properties
So I can have output as

```
  innerid="1",
  innername="Name1",
    {
      id= "1", name= "One"
      id= "2", name= "Two"
      id= "4", name= "Four"
    }
  innerid="2",
  innername="Name2",
    {
      id= "3", name= "Three"
      id= "6", name= "Six"
      id= "8", name= "Eight"
    }
```

I tried 
`.GroupBy(a => a.nestedList.First().innerid).ToList()`
But I am not getting required output.

Comment: I'm guessing the output is Json?

Comment: `.GroupBy(a => a.nestedList.First().innerid).ToList()` is not an attempt to solve the problem. You have to try harder than that.

Comment: I don't see how this list is nested; or am I missing that it contains another list?

Comment: Yes class A contains a List of class B using property nestedList. @SebastianHofmann

Comment: @WillyDavidJr True, but in most cases a nested list means `List<List<B>>`.

Comment: Welll you have a point. Maybe the description should be corrected or change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to reverse the hierarchy, so grouping by the nested-B and list the parent-A as children?

```
var groups = aList
   .SelectMany(a => a.nestedList.Select(b => new { A = a, B = b }))
   .GroupBy(x => new { x.B.innerid, x.B.innername })
   .Select(g => new { 
       g.Key.innerid, 
       g.Key.innername, 
       aItems = g.Select(x => new { x.A.id, x.A.name }) 
    });
```

Instead of selecting anonymous types you can also select the original A and B instances.

Comment: Thank you all for your time. Solution provided by Tim and Titans has resolved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the items from the result must contain items of type `A`, you could use query syntax to solve this:

```
 var grouping = from a in collectionOfA
                from b in a.nestedList
                group a by new { b.innerid, b.innername } into g
                select new
                {
                    innerid = g.Key.innerid,
                    innername = g.Key.innername,
                    items = g.ToList()
                };
```